# Is a p-value of .047 statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I ran a Kruskal-Wallis H test and the result was .000. So, I ran a post hoc pairwise comparison to see where the difference precisely exists, and one of the results was a p-value of .047. SPSS did not highlight it in yellow like the other significant results.
Should I report it as a statistically significant or insignificant different?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Right or wrong, a typical standard for statistical significance is being $0.05$ or lower, which your p-value satisfies. That your software did not highlight the values makes me wonder what else is happening. I don’t know SPSS, but for those who do, what procedures or functions did you use? Since the value is so close to the $0.05$ threshold, I could imagine something involving multiple testing keeping the test from being significant. // Why not just give the p-value, rather than declare significance or insignificance?

Comment: I have to report and interpret the p-value as well, rather than reporting the figure only.

Comment: If your significance level is at $p=0.05$, then it would be significant under your test regime.  I agree with Dave about just listing the p-value rather than stating whether it meets (or not) some arbitrary threshold of so-called significance.  The software should be (again I say ***should*** be) irrelevant as the results should be only dependent on the test used not the software (i.e. you should get the same result doing the same test in other software).

Comment: How did you do your pairwise comparisons? I don't see the option in the Kruskal-Wallis menu in SPSS. Also how did you get SPSS to highlight "significant" tests? I also don't see this in SPSS.

Comment: Did you consider any correction for multiple testing? If so, how was this done?

Answer (score 3):

Given that a p value of .047 is more precise than .05, it is safe to say that your value is significant (if you set a cutoff of $a = .05$ before your analysis at least). Even if it rounds up to .05, .047 is still factually less than the cutoff. Therefore, you may reject the null hypothesis for your pairwise comparisons. Keep in mind, as Frank Harrell suggested in the comments, that these cutoffs are arbitrary and that it is important to obtain more information to understand the actual difference in pairwise comparisons, such as effect sizes like Cohen's d, confidence intervals, or other relevant information that may explain things such as the magnitude of the effect or precision in your estimate.

If your concern is writing up a manuscript, you can do what others have suggested and write out the p value explicitly whenever explaining your results in a paper. The exception to that rule may be some absurdly low p value that requires a lot of scientific notation, where you would instead just use p < .001 for simplification.

Page 2 of [this APA guide](https://apastyle.apa.org/instructional-aids/numbers-statistics-guide.pdf) states:

> Report exact p values to two or three decimals (e.g., p = .006, p =
> .03)

as well as:

> However, report p values less than .001 as “p < .001.”

I would follow their advice, as it is typically what I see in manuscripts in my domain.

Comment: Just keep in mind that "statistical significance" means next to nothing and all significant thresholds are arbitrary.

Comment: I almost included more about that in my original answer, but I've edited my answer to clarify your point.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand and everyone else, thank you very much. And yes, my concern is reporting the results not of Kruskal-Wallis test, but the variables' mean rank output related to the KW test. So, any idea other than reporting just the figures? I mean, what do these mean ranks imply/indicate? I can report them like in order from highest to lowest means, mentioning the mean figures as well. Can I add to that?

Comment: This page explains how to understand SPSS output for KW tests and how to report them: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php#:~:text=Reporting%20the%20Output%20of%20the%20Kruskal%2DWallis%20H%20Test&text=A%20Kruskal%2DWallis%20H%20test%20showed%20that%20there%20was%20a,and%2021.35%20for%20Drug%20C.

Comment: Nothing much explained there in the link provided, @ShawnHemelstrand. Though, if you can add to the explanation in the link, I'll be grateful. Thank you, anyway, too.

Comment: It explicitly tells you how to report the statistics in the Reporting the Output of the Kruskal-Wallis H Test section, including the mean ranks you asked about. If you are worried about the order, I don't think there is any specific thing you need regarding that, but you can order it by mean rank or by group if you feel it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it is bigger than the [*significance level*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) that the specified significance level $\alpha$, which is often taken to be $0.05$... or $0.005$ - so there is no definite answer to your question.